# How can i get binary from image using node ftp?

Tags: node.js, ftp, sharp

I want to get binary from image to rotate then, using `sharp.rotate();`

I try to do this `content += chunk;` but dosent work.

```
let Client     = require('ftp');
    let fs      = require('fs');
    let sharp   = require('sharp');

    let path = 'users/'+userId+'/headerImage/header';
    let Ftp = new Client();//create new istance of Ftp

    //Start. Here we get image from server
    await Ftp.on('ready', function(){
        Ftp.get(path, async function(err, stream){
            if(err){
                res.status(400).send(err);
            };

            var content = '';
            await stream.on('data', async (chunk) => {
                content += chunk;
              });

            await stream.on('end', async function(){
                console.log(content);
                let image = await sharp(content);

                await image
                    .rotate(90)
                    .toBuffer()
                    .then(async data => {
                        console.log(data);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                Ftp.end();
            });
        });
    });
    await Ftp.connect({
        host: fileTransferProtocol.host,
        port: fileTransferProtocol.port,
        user: fileTransferProtocol.user,
        password: fileTransferProtocol.pass
    });
```

console: `Error: [Error: Input file is missing]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem you are having is that you are not handling the incoming data as a buffer. The `stream` variable inside the `Ftp.get` callback is of type [`ReadableStream`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams). By default, stream data will be returned as `Buffer` objects unless you specify an encoding for the data, using the [`readable.setEncoding()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_setencoding_encoding) method.

For your specific purpose, you want to handle the data as a `Buffer` object, since that is what the `sharp` function is expecting. To store the incoming data into a `Buffer` modify what happens on the `data` event.

```
var content = new Buffer(0);

stream.on("data", async chunk => {
  content = Buffer.concat([content, chunk]);
});
```

Also, I don't think you are using `async/await` duly. The `ftp` module runs with callbacks and events, not promises. Appending those functions with `await` won't make them run synchronously.

Please check the following link to find more information about this feature:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

If you want to us `async/await` to handle your `ftp` requests try this module:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-ftp

It provides an asynchronous interface for communicating with an FTP server.